# NPM Install Refusing to Create Node Modules?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, installation, module

I am trying to open a cloned project of mine, however I am thrown with this error:

**'react-scripts' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.**

Now, when I noticed I do not have a node_modules folder. I do a quick npm install in my terminal, it will create the node_modules folder for a second, throw tons of errors at me and then delete it automatically.

Any ideas on what could be causing this?

Comment: Show us the errors when executing `npm install`. *tons of errors* isn't really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the package.JSON file, it’s a bit tricky.

But, if you have a package.JSON + a package-lock.JSON, it’s possible the react-scripts is in one and not the other.

By default, npm-install is scanning the package-lock.JSON vs the original: package.JSON.

Do not delete the package.JSON, but (** read NOTE before these steps!) consider deleting the node_modules folder + package-lock.JSON then, run `npm install`.

Running `npm install` again will restore the package-lock.JSON + node_modules folder.

NOTE: if this is part of a group project, do not delete the package-lock.JSON, instead audit your package.JSON file and make sure it contains the proper dependencies.